# Adding a library Android-studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm having trouble when i add achartengine-1.1.0.jar in my project. 
When i add

```
compile file('libs.achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
```

in build.gradle, Gradle shows the following message :

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':NativeCharts'.
Cannot convert the provided notation to an object of type Dependency: /home/***/NativeChartsProject/NativeCharts/libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar.
  The following types/formats are supported:
    - Instances of Dependency.
    - Strings/CharSequences, e.g. 'org.gradle:gradle-core:1.0'.
    - Maps, e.g. [group: 'org.gradle', name: 'gradle-core', version: '1.0'].
    - FileCollections, e.g. files('some.jar', 'someOther.jar').
    - Projects, e.g. project(':some:project:path').
    - ClassPathNotation, e.g. gradleApi().
  Comprehensive documentation on dependency notations is available in DSL reference for DependencyHandler type.
```

Thanks in advance.
Fab.

Comment: i changes file to files and now i have : 

Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':NativeCharts'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':NativeCharts:classpath'.
   > Problems pinging owner of lock '640513271418860208' at port: 50072

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dependency should read `compile files(...)`, not `compile file(...)`. Also in the above you write the path as `libs.achartengine-1.1.0.jar`, this should be `libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar`.